# Using variable from user action in shortcut with Visual Studio 2008 Installer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a shortcut I need to make based off of user input.  I created a Textboxes (A) page in the file actions of my Visual Studio 2008 application.  I changed the edit1 box to STUDYNAME.

In the variable, I used [StudyName], [STUDYNAME], $[STUDYNAME] and "[STUDYNAME]"

None of them worked.

Any help would be great.

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the shortcut name is not [formatted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368609%28VS.85%29.aspx):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371847(VS.85).aspx

So you cannot use a property for a shortcut name. Instead, you can try creating a [custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368066%28VS.85%29.aspx) which gets the property value and renames the shortcut.

There is no predefined support for this in Visual Studio, so you will have to write the custom action code yourself.